# Verbs with no gerund

Tags: глаголы

I read that verbs **есть**, **ждать**, **мочь**, **петь**, **пить**, **спать** have no gerund (деепричастие).

So, if I ever need to convey a progressive mood of these verbs (respectively, *eating, waiting, being able to, singing, drinking, sleeping*), is there a way around?

Comment: Do you mean "I am eating, he was waiting" etc?

Comment: Do you mean a verb or a noun derived from this verb?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing to add a translation for "gerund" as no-one so far seems to understand the question.

Comment: this is not what we learned at school as Gerund in English (in my time as least), this is present participle, even though they bear the same grammatical form they function differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerund

> есть - поедание (ядение - archaic)
>
> ждать - ожидание
>
> мочь - обладание способностью, способность
>
> петь - на/рас-певание, пение
>
> пить - рас/вы-пивание, распитие
>
> спать - сон

When i use gerund forms in my speech i often pause fabricating a proper form in my head, because they're not very typical for Russian.

For some verbs gerund and a noun can be the same word like for **спать**, therе's a word **спаньё**, but it's very low register by modern standards.

<sup>In constructions where English would have a gerund Russian, particularly in its spoken form, has subordinate clause with a verb, e.g.</sup>
<sup>*Instead of **singing** you'd better do some work*

*Вместо **того, чтобы петь**, ты бы лучше поработал*

An equivalent with gerund such as "*Вместо **пения** ты бы лучше поработал*" is also correct but isn't very usable.</sup>

---

If the question was about **present participle** rather than gerund, then the  modified list is as follows

> есть - по/съ-едая
>
> ждать - ожидая
>
> мочь - умея, обладая способностью
>
> петь - на/рас-певая
>
> пить - рас/вы-пивая
>
> спать - находясь/пребывая во сне

As evident from the list quite a few of them can form present participle through addition of a prefix

Comment: I'm sorry I did not make myself clear enough. Actually, i took the word "gerund" from my French textbooks, which use the word *"gérondif présent"* to refer to the ending *"ая"* on verbs, and *"gérondif passé"* to refer to the ending *"ив"*.

But yes, I meant the present participle, if that is the correct terminology. And I was, as you guessed, looking for alternative verbs to replace those common ones with the "ая" ending.

Comment: Just one more thing: on cooljugator.com, **"пья"** is cited as the present participle of **пить**. Is this correct?

Comment: @swrutra no problem, i personally am very fond of unconventional grammatical forms, if it can be pronounced and there's no alternative why not use it? but practically speaking if *пья* exists it must be archaic and is very unusual in modern language, i came across a participle *пия*, it sounds more euphonuc but is also an oddity in modern language

Answer (score 4):

If you mean continious aspect, we don't have it. We have one present, one past and one future. So it doesn't matter if it happens every day or now, we have got one form "Я ем, ты ешь, он, она ест, мы едим, вы едите, они едят." You can only add when.

If you mean деепричастие, that's another question. Yes, there's a way.
For example "we went along the road singing". There's no деепричастие настоящего времени, but you can always say:

> Мы шли по дороге и пели.(The idea is the same, that of the simultaneous action).

You can also use synonyms:for ждать, ожидая, for есть– жуя, кушая,for пить - отпивая,запивая,глотая etc.

Comment: As for ожидая, кушая and запивая, that's exactly what i was looking for. When I told "gerund", I meant the present participle which, on the subordinate clause, introduces a simultaneous action to that of the main clause. I had in mind the **-ая** ending.

Answer (score 2):

**If you mean a verb:**

Since there is no progressive mood in Russian you don't have to worry. Just use present, past or future tense and "сейчас", "в тот момент" or whatever is suitable:

> I am eating  - Я (сейчас) ем.
>
> She was singing when I came in - Когда я вошёл, она пела.
>
> Tomorrow midnight, we will be drinking champagne  - Завтра в полночь мы будем пить шампанское.

**If you mean a noun:**

You don't have to worry again. Just use the verb itself or the coresponding noun:

> I love singing - Я люблю петь / Я люблю пение
>
> I like her singing - Мне нравится, как она поет / Мне нравится её пение
>
> Eating was their favorite pleasure - (По)есть было их любимым удовльствием / Еда была их любимым удовольствием.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that verbs есть, ждать, мочь, петь, пить, спать have no gerund (деепричастие).
>
> So, if I ever need to convey a progressive mood of these verbs (respectively, eating, waiting, being able to, singing, drinking, sleeping), is there a way around?

В русском языке мы обычно говорим "когда (можно заменить на "пока") я что-то делал(а)...".

Когда я ел, я оглядывал роскошный кабинет директора.
Пока я ел, мои новые знакомые то и дело пытались обокрасть меня.

Есть.

Можно уточнить о каком приеме пищи идет речь:
Завтракая/обедая/ужиная
За завтраком/полдником/обедом/ужином

Можно сказать иначе, если прием пищи неплотный:

Перекусывая (название еды)
За перекусом

Если текст неформальный или литературный, можно использовать следующее:

Уплетая (пищу/бутерброд/шоколад...)
Треская (название еды)
Поглощая (название еды) - подчеркивает огромные количества съеденного
Пожирая (название еды) - оскорбительно, подчеркивает чудовищно огромные количества съеденного.

Хотя есть и другие фразы:
Принимая пищу
За приемом пищи
Принимая трапезу (звучит несколько устаревше)
За приемом трапезы
Трапезничая (абсолютно устарело)

Ждать.

Есть слово с чрезвычайно близким к нему значением - "ожидать", которое имеет деепричастие.

Ожидая автомеханика, я перекидывался редкими язвительными замечаниями о качестве дорог.

Помимо этого, в русском языке есть устойчивое выражение "считать минуты", которое означает "с нетерпением ждать чего-то".

Считая минуты до следующего свидания со своей любимой, студент, окрещенный мной "Ромео", перебирал струны гитары и заливался пением.

Еще один способ заменить деепричастие для "ждать" - заменить его "дожидаясь". Оно подчеркивает продолжительность ожидания.

Для меня его корректно использовать разве что для прошедшего времени и для чего-то регулярно совершаемого.

Дожидаясь моей подруги сердца, я с нетерпением смотрел на часы, стрелки которых едва ползли по циферблату, тем самым вызывая во мне бурю эмоций.

Мочь.

Умея

Умея писать программы как на Java, так и на C++, мой друг получал нескромное количество заказов.

Имея возможность/возможности
Обладая возможностью/возможностями

Даже имея возможность скрыться с места преступления, он решил сдаться полиции из-за терзаний совести.

Множественное число показывает, что возможности были шире/многочисленние.

Петь

Напевать - петь легко и беззаботно, чаще всего тихо. Есть деепричастие напевая.

Распевать - петь широко, громко. Есть деепричастие распевая.

Заливаяться пением - петь увлеченно, чаще всего - громко. Деепричастный оборот - заливаясь пением.